# Regex to capture everything except the previous capture

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse some strings where the values could be given like:

> stuff "Something" stuff

or

> stuff 'something' stuff

I solved this bit easily with:

`(?<quote>"|')(?<quoted_value>[^'"]+)\k<quote>`

However I've come across a problem where I have:

> stuff "Today's Top 10" stuff

And I thought I could use the captured quote as the argument for the `quoted_value` pattern like so:

`(?<quote>"|')(?<quoted_value>[^\k<quote>]+)\k<quote>`

But I get

> 

```
Unrecognized escape sequence \k
```

How can I use the first `quote` capture value as a condition to capture everything until that value is found again?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `\k`?

Comment: @toto `\k` is `Matches the value of a previously captured named group, specified by name.`

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/IWV6LX/1) working for you?

Comment: @Toto OH, LEGEND! Yes it works perfectly. Didn't think of using a sub-pattern. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Tempered Greedy Pattern](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?<quote>['"])(?:(?!\k<quote>).)*\k<quote>
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/IWV6LX/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like a good resource too!